# Expand range to url

Tags: javascript, range

Im trying to use ranges to check if the mouse is over an url, but I dont know how to tell the range that expand to get the full url, not just each word in it.

Here is an example to show the problem: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3AtL/)

I will use this code in an editable iframe. If an user write an url, I want to give him the possibility to open it although it isn't an anchor element but plain text. Im not sure if can achieve that, but i want to try it.

Comment: You'll have to walk the string backwards until it finds the start of the URL, or line, then walk forwards and validate the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that the `expand()` method of Range is non-standard and only supported in WebKit. Another is that `document.caretRangeFromPoint()` is also WebKit-only. Yet another is that there is no way of specifying a regular expression to match when identifying a word.

One option is the new [TextRange module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule) of my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library, which works in all major browsers and provides a more flexible `expand()` method of ranges. There's also a work-in-progress position module that provides a cross-browser implementation of `document.caretRangeFromPoint()` (which is standardized as [`document.caretPositionFromPoint()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-document-caretpositionfrompoint)).

Unfortunately, the position module is flaky in Firefox, but I intend to fix it soon. Also, the following demo doesn't work in IE at the moment, for reasons I think related to jsFiddle. So overall this is far from satisfactory, but may give you some ideas.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q3AtL/5/

Comment: Very much thanks for you solution Tim. I forget to say that I just need that this works with Chrome (is an Chrome extension). I have a last question to choose Rangy, can i attach an event to a range (just the click event)? I have tried with rangy-events.js but I cant make it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Masta: There's no built-in way in the browser to attach an event to a range. Rangy's range-events.js is the start of a very speculative attempt something like that but is a long way from being usable.

Comment: @Tom Still is, by far, my best option. Thanks for rangy and for your help :)